# Collecting inputs from user within foreach loop (Using HTML and pHp)

Tags: php, html

I want the user to be able to input details regarding each exercise that is listed. However the number of exercises that show up is not set (user could select a verying number of exercises so I cannot use a set number of input boxes). How do I make it so that for each time the for loop is ran, a new input box will show up (1 for each exercise)?

```
foreach($exer->results() as $ex){
echo $ex->Name."<br/>";
// for each exercise I want to collect an input from user
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the exercise count from the user. You loop that amount of iterations in a `for loop`. Inside the loop add text fields. make sure you use `name` like `data[user][]`.

```
$user_ex_count = 5; // Lets say you get 5 from a text box
for ( $x = 0; $x < $user_ex_count; $x++ ){
    echo '<input type="text" name="data[user][]">';
}
```

Then when you submit, your `$_POST` will have `$_POST['data']` (which is an array.

So you can do,

```
if ( isset($_POST['data']) ){
    foreach( $_POST['data'] as $key -> $userInput ){
        echo $userInput; // user input values
    }
}
```

This is just a dummy code to let you understand the flow. So that you can work on.

Hope this helps!

Comment: one question, say the number of exercises is obtained from a SELECT query from my database, how do I know what to set $user_ex_count to?

Comment: is that number already in the database for that specific user? In that can you can write a `SELECT` query, `fetch` that value and assign that value to the `$user_ex_count` variable. if you write your code based on `$user_ex_count` you can set value to this variable from either database, user input, etc.. but still the other stuff will run

Answer (score 0):

Is that want you want

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST))
{

  echo $_POST['value'][0]; // First input
  echo $_POST['value'][1]; // Second input
  // and so on
} else {
  foreach($exer->results() as $ex){
    echo '<input type="text" name="value[]">';
}
```